# Logging to a website using Python's requests

Tags: python, web, logging, python-requests

So i am currently doing a project for my school and I need to login to our canteen website using Python. I am using requests, but the code is not working. It just redirects me to starting page, instead of the user page. I have tried this code on other website and it worked just fine. I have found out, that this website uses some JavaServer pages. May that be the problem?

I have tried a few tutorials on Youtube and even searched something here, but nothing worked for me.

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 OPR/58.0.3135.53'
}


login_data = {
    'j_username': '**',
    'j_password': '**',
    'terminal': 'false',
    'type': 'web',
    '_spring_security_remember_me': 'on'
}


with requests.session() as c:
    url = 'https://jidelna.mgo.opava.cz:6204/faces/secured/info.jsp?terminal=false&keyboard=false&printer=false'


    r = c.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="html.parser")
    login_data['_csrf'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name':  '_csrf'})['value']
    login_data['targetUrl'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name':  'targetUrl'})['value']

    r = c.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the post request to the wrong url. If you use developer tools to inspect the login form you can get the `action` attribute of the form.

[image]

In the network tab in developer tools you can see the POST request being made and the parameters. You should make the post request to `https://jidelna.mgo.opava.cz:6204/j_spring_security_check`

[image]

[image]

If all of these does not work, also consider emulating the headers as far as possible. There is a cookie being sent, so you might have to use [session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) with Requests.

[image]

If everything else fails there is always [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Thank you so much! I am now posting to the url you wrote and everything is working just fine! You are awesome, thanks.